# PostGIS- convert points to polygon based on multiple shared attributes

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, convex-hull

I have a PostgreSQL PostGIS point table (not multi-points). I want to convert the points to polygons (using convex-hull?) grouping the points by shared attributes from 2 columns.

[image: points to polygon example]

In this example, 'alpha' and 'beta' are text from a VARCHAR 'column1' and the numbers are from an id integer type 'column2'.

What is the best way to go about this? Please keep in mind the final table I'll be working on is large (30 million points (100s of points making up each grouping), 6GB table size).

Comment: @BERA yeah sorry that's just a mistake in my drawing and understanding of convex hull.

Comment: Have you tried [ST_ConvexHull](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConvexHull.html) and grouping by the two columns? Should work

Comment: Questions seeking the "best" of anything are problematic here, since they imply an *opinion-based* component. I suggest you build a covering index on the attribute used to union the points, union the points, and compute the convex hull. If you encounter a problem, then you'll have a question which isn't future-dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE schema.polytable AS
SELECT column1, column2, ST_AsText(ST_CONVEXHULL(ST_COLLECT(geomcolumn))) AS newgeomcolumn
FROM schema.sourcetable
GROUP BY column1, column2
```

As suggested by someone else, this works in this scenario.

Comment: You should really have accepted the answer of @bm13563 rather than copying it and saying it works.

Comment: @JohnPowell his answer was removed for some reason.

Comment: Ah, ok, fair enough, and a bit strange, seeing as it was correct. Apologies for false accusation.

Comment: Maybe in this case it's better to create an index on the columns first ? like a btree(column1, column2). If there is performance issues on a very big table that can be worth the try